# Split string by spaces with defined length

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio

I need to split an addres lines into 3 parts, each one of different size. In this case: 40, 30 and 30 characters. I want to split input string by spaces so it makes some sense.

Fot this, I wrote a reular expression: `(.{1,32})([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}` and tried it in this website: https://regex101.com. It worked!

I moved to Visual Studio to write some code to check it out:

```
public static void TEST()
{
    List<string> ok = new List<string>();
    List<string> err = new List<string>();

    var lista = GetLista();
    foreach (string dir in lista)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(.{1,32})([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}");
        dir = dir.Trim();

        GroupCollection cap = regex.Match(dir).Groups;

        if (cap.Count == 0) err.Add(dir);
        else ok.Add($"{dir};{cap[0].Value};{(cap.Count > 1 ? cap[1].Value.Trim() : "")};{(cap.Count > 2 ? cap[2].Value : "")};{(cap.Count > 3 ? cap[3].Value.Trim() : "")}";);
    }

    File.WriteAllLines("ok.txt", txt);
    File.WriteAllLines("er.txt", err);
}
```

Results are very differens, it doesn't match at all. Are regex somehow different in C#?

Is there any other way to achive this?

---

EDITED: Regexs given where differents.

---

UPDATE: I'll provide an example. Let's take this string:
"ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE LA PALMA".

c# result: "ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE L";"ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE L";;

Wanted: "ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE";"LA PALMA";""

I think the problem is regex is not taking the whole string, just part of it.

Comment: Please **[edit]** the question and give some good input examples + what each produces + what it needs to produce instead.

Comment: Please post your example string that you are parsing with the regex. In that way, we can perform the required testing at our end also.

Comment: I modified it, any idea now? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to match the whole string, so you need to add anchors, `^` and `$`. Next, you need to get the *captured* substrings, not the *whole match*. Note that the `GroupCollection` returns all captured group values and the whole match as the first item. So, you `match.Groups` will contain 1 + the number of capturing groups values. You need to ignore the first item.

Also, to check if a group matched, you need to use `cap[x].Success` rather than `cap.Count > x`.

So, you need a code like this:

```
foreach (string dir in lista)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(dir, @"^(.{1,32})([ ]+.{1,30})?([ ]+.{1,30})?$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var cap = match.Groups;
        ok.Add($"{dir};{cap[1].Value};{(cap[2].Success ? cap[2].Value.Trim() : "")};{(cap[3].Success ? cap[3].Value : "")}");
    }
    else
    {
         err.Add(dir);
    }
}
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/cyz7O0) online:

```
List<string> ok = new List<string>();
List<string> err = new List<string>();

var lista = new[] { "ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE LA PALMA" };
foreach (string dir in lista)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(dir, @"^(.{1,32})([ ]+.{1,30})?([ ]+.{1,30})?$");
    if (match.Success)
    {
        var cap = match.Groups;
        ok.Add($"{dir};{cap[1].Value};{(cap[2].Success ? cap[2].Value.Trim() : "")};{(cap[3].Success ? cap[3].Value : "")}");
    }
    else
    {
         err.Add(dir);
    }
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", ok));
```

Output:

```
ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE LA PALMA;ERIK ADESIR COMPANY LA ISLA DE;LA PALMA;
```

Comment: It seems to work. Definitely problem was capturing whole string. BTW, GroupCollection elements doesn't have Success property. That's why I used Count instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be that your given Regex in c#

```
new Regex(@"(.{1,40})([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}");
```

is not equals to the one You used as test:

```
(.{1,32})([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}([ ]+.{1,30}){0,1}
```

In c# you start with (.{1,**40**} 
but your example is  (.{1,**32**})

Comment: Actually I have to split name (length:32,30,30) and address (length:40,30,30). That's why my example was wrong. I'll edit it.